# Removing double-quotes around Keys in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

my array has keys with double-quotes "" around them, how can I remove them?

I'm generating my object from input fields like this:

```js
var obj = {};
obj.Firstname = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
obj.Lastname = document.getElementById("surname").value;
var jsonStringObj = {
    users: [JSON.stringify(obj)]
};
console.log(jsonStringObj)
```

Result is like this:

```js
users: ["{"Firstname":"","Lastname":""}"] <<-- wrong
```

Expected array:

```js
users: [{Firstname:"john",Lastname:"doe"}] <<-- I want this
```

I have tried the following unsuccessful attempts:

```js
var string = JSON.stringify(array);
string.replace (/"/g,'');
```

Comment: There is no need to stringify your object, `var jsonStringObj = {users: [obj]};` should suffice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write JSON.stringify to convert it in the string, it would add the double quotes to your keys.

You just have to write **obj** directly, it would behave as the normal object and not string.

So please update your code of lines with the below code. It should resolve your problem.

```
var obj = {};
 obj.Firstname = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
 obj.Lastname = document.getElementById("surname").value;
 var jsonStringObj = {users: [obj]};
 console.log(jsonStringObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.parse(),this will change a json to object. here is the example:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(users)
```

if you want to change an object to string you use JSON.stringify(obj)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to stringify the object at all.

```js
var obj = {};
 obj.Firstname = "";
 obj.Lastname = "";
var obj2 = {users: [obj]};
console.log(obj2);
```